# Python loop using zip with assignment

Tags: python

I'm trying to use a for loop in order to modify values in a list, based on values on a second list. Hence I though that the "zip" function would come in handy, however I'm not getting the result I'm expecting. See an example here:

```
list_a = [0,0,0,0]
list_b = [1,2,3,4]

for a, b in zip(list_a, list_b):
a = b*2
```

I though that this modifies list_a, however it does not. My understanding was that, inside the loop, "a" was first equal to `list_a[0]`, then `list_a[1]`, etc, in other words views of the list.

I have actually 2 questions:

a) what are "a" and "b" inside the loop, if they are not views of the two lists?

b) is there a pythonic way of implementing this loop (i.e. something different from looping over `i in range(len(list_a))`?

Comment: pythonic way ? probably do your operations in a comprehension and create a new list, assigning to list_a at the end.

Comment: `a=..` does not modify `a[0]`. It just assigns a new value to the variable.  `view` is a numpy array concept, not a list one.

Comment: "was first equal to list_a[0], then list_a[1], etc, in other words views of the list." No, they are not views. `list_a[i]` *returns the object contained by that index in the list*. `a = list_a[0]` makes the name `a` reference some object, that happens to be the first element of `list_a`, but that object has no knowledge of that

Comment: They are just another references, not pointers.

Answer (score 2):

You can try something like:

```
list_a = [0,0,0,0]
list_b = [1,2,3,4]

for i, b in enumerate(list_b):
    list_a[i] = b*2
```

You can get the same result with:

```
[b*2 for b in list_b]
```